# Scroll in vertical idangero.us swiper for mobile

Tags: javascript, css, swiper.js

So, I've got a typical vertical swiper working really good in my mobile client.

Everything goes according to plan, unless the content is larger than the screen.
Then the user can't scroll to reach the end of the content, because the slide changes.

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
direction: 'vertical',
pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination'
},
scrollbar: {
    el: '.swiper-scrollbar'
},
spaceBetween: 20
});
```

And my CSS:

```
.swiper-container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.swiper-slide {
height: auto;
}
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff, including: 
css overflow, slidesPerView, touchReleaseOnEdges and freeMode with freeModeSticky.

The only thing that almost worked was touchReleaseOnEdges, but it can't be called usable.

I essentially need [this](https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/090-vertical.html) plus [this](https://idangero.us/swiper/demos/160-scroll-container.html).

Comment: can you add a close button to close the slider?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, check out the edited question ;)

Comment: can you add an icon that when clicked will add a class .closed with javascript to .swiper-container so you would then have access to the div beneath it in the dom with text in it. thus: .swiper-container.closed { height: 0; }

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. No, I do not want any buttons.
If I was allowed to add buttons I could skip using the swipe gesture completely and navigate the slides using those, making my life way easier!

Comment: put the text in as an extra slide instead of an image? As you have with "Slide 1".